# tkinter won't pack any widgets on mac

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

When I try to use the pack method to show the widgets nothing happens. I have also tried the grid method but that does not work either.

This is what I have tried:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Funksjoner")
window.geometry('500x500')

label = ttk.Label(master = window, text = 'Graftegner', font =('calibri',24))
label.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

However when I run the code I just get an empty window.
[Image of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUxgX.png)

Comment: macos doesn't run on ttk. Here is link https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/

Comment: It is mentioned in few questions on SO that the built-in version of Python in certain MacOS is broken.  Try reinstalling Python from python.org.

Comment: @toyotaSupra: What do you mean by _"macos doesn't run on ttk"_? While technically true (MacOS is an OS, not an application), ttk works fine on the Macintosh.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley. Where did you get information? I tried with my friend.

Comment: @toyotaSupra: I've used ttk plenty of times in my own projects.

Comment: Install Python from source (python.org) to get tkinter to work on macOS. Call your script using the source-downloaded executable: `your_new_python3 your_script.py`, and you can alias it to something like `alias p3s=/usr/local/bin/python3` in your shell startup file(s), so you can call `p3s your_script.py`.