# Buttons with tkinter unresponsive until window is resized

Tags: python, tkinter

I've made a simple calculator using tkinter. When the window launches, the responsiveness of the buttons is sporadic. Sometimes clicking them works, other times it doesn't. However, after I manually resize or move the window the buttons always work.

[Video of the issue](https://app.screencast.com/1cgvfuBQIDLpc)

Here's the general layout of my code:

```py
from tkinter import *

def button_click(number):
    current = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))

root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")

e = Entry(root, width=45, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

button_1 = Button(root, text="1", command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_1.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_2 = Button(root, text="2", command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I first tried to resolve this by force updating the GUI:

```py
root.update_idletasks()
```

This did not work. Next I tried programatically resizing the window:

```py
root.geometry('1x1')
root.geometry('')
```

I also tried delaying the main loop:

```py
root.after(100, root.mainloop)
```

Comment: "It is mentioned in few questions on SO that the built-in version of Python in certain MacOS is broken. Try reinstalling Python from python.org. – 
acw1668
 Nov 13 at 10:29 " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77472883/tkinter-wont-pack-any-widgets-on-mac

Comment: I have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73056296/tkinter-on-mac-shows-up-as-a-black-screen/73186351#73186351) which outlines the steps for installing/updating/replacing tkinter on Mac OS, if that helps!